# How can I convert an empty character sequence in C++ to its equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am using ctypes in Python to access functions from a shared C library. One of the parameters for one of the functions requires an empty array of the type `char` to write error messages into. The code for the array in C++ is simple;

```
char messageBuffer[256];
```

I would like to write the equivalent in Python so that I can pass an array containing the correct data type to the function. I've tried simply creating and array in Python of length 256, but I get the error message;

```
mydll.TLBP2_error_message(m_handle, errorCode, messageBuffer)

ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't know anything about `ctyes` but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699800/python-using-ctypes-to-pass-a-char-array-and-populate-results) help? Not sure if a duplicate.

Comment: Please format your question according to [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add the *C* function header, and the *Python* code that uses it (not only the call, but also loading the lib, and preparing the stuff for the call).